# What's the difference between File stream in C and iostream in C++?

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages, stream

What's the difference between File (File* pointer)stream in C and iostream in C++?

Why are they both called stream, do they have something in common?

Answer (score 9):

They both deal with files, and "stream" is simply a very general term for data that is coming in pieces from some source.

The difference mainly is that C++'s iostream objects are classes/objects, and C file data is accessed through the defined f*() functions.

So basically, same task, different style of interface.

Answer (score 5):

They are both typically buffered, which means that the I/O you do on a stream does not match 1:1 the I/O done on the underlying system object (e.g. a file).

For instance a `fread()` call to read 2 bytes could attempt to read 1,024 bytes from the file, which might in turn only return 57 if you were that close to end of file. The difference is all hidden by the stream implementation, which will return 2 bytes and remember that is has a further 55 in its buffers. It will thus satisfy the next read request without hitting the file level at all.

EDIT: It's worth pointing out that the default error streams in both languages (`stderr` and `cerr`, respectively) are not buffered. This is a big win, since it increases the chance of getting your output out in time. When chasing weird crash bugs by sprinkling code with `printf()` statements, it's a very good idea to print to the error stream for this particular reason.

Comment: Streams are not necessarily buffered; stderr and cerr would lose a good deal of functionality if they had to be.  The idea of a stream is that it's a sequence of undifferentiated bytes, and buffering is more of an implementation or OS thing.

Comment: I see your statement "For instance a fread() call to read 2 bytes could read 1024 bytes from the file, which might in turn only return 57 if you were that close to end of file." Does that mean a fread can go on and read beyond EoF ?

Comment: @Invictus Nah, of course not (the filesystem wouldn't allow it), it will truncate the read at the EOF. I'll edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Both are different interfaces for OS I/O subsystem.

Comment: what do you mean by "system entity"?

Comment: I meant input/output subsystem of operation system.

Answer (score 1):

C++ Streams are extensible in two ways that C files are not:

- You can create your own stream type
  and all streamable objects will
  automatically work with it.
- If stream operators are defined for a class, any object of that class can be written to and read
  from any stream.

Answer (score 0):

compare file stream between C and Java

Answer (score -1):

it's easier to tell their familiarity than differences, because theirs only one familiarity: they both bear one term(stream) that's common in the programming world.

stream is often used to refer to un-formated raw data which are just a chunk of binary bytes. Think of the file content that's copied to the newly allocated memory, before they are parsed(that is the moment immediately after they are copied over) they are just a chunk of binary bytes to you. So you only have methods like seek() to access them, which works on a basis of bytes.

Compare that to Text Files that you can ReadLine(), WriteLine(), which work in pre-format entities(called lines in this case). You'll get the idea.